# AngularJs ng-repeat form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.4.7. I am using an `ng-repeat` in a `div` surrounded by `form` as follows

```
     <form name="myForm">
        <div ng-repeat="product in ProductList">
       <input name="ProductName" ng-model="ProductName">
</div>
</form>
```

When i validate errors show up on all the ProductNames even if its valid, i know i have to use `ng-form` but i can not get it to work

The Angular docs were not enough. And could not find a solution that works

Thanks

Comment: This is still a bit vague... Can you provide more information on what you're trying to do and provide some JS?

Comment: There is actually no JS involved so far. I think i found the solution though will mess around for a while then update

Answer (score 1):

it's not a validation issue, you just have each input assigned to the same model. Try

```
<input name="ProductName[{{$index}}]" ng-model="product.name">
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply mate, will try it after work today. It was late night here

Answer (score 0):

change your line one to this :
     `<form  name="myForm" novalidate>`